# Convert object to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "1": "Technology",
  "2": "Startup",
  "3": "IT",
}
```

and I need to convert it to an array of objects that would look like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "Technology"},
  {id: 2, name: "Startup"},
  {id: 3, name: "IT"}
]
```

What would be the cleanest & efficient way to do this?

Comment: @OwaisAslam, this is definitely not a duplicate of that question.  Both involve mapping objects and arrays, and similar tools, but they have very different starting and ending shapes

Comment: @KyleMit What did I say?

Comment: oh, it was just a duplicate suggestion - sorry for the lack of context - i also flagged the comment as no longer necessary (no penalties to authors for that) so I guess it's since been removed - i'll remove this and my original comment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with `Object.keys()`:

```js
let data = {
    "1": "Technology",
    "2": "Startup",
    "3": "IT",
};

let result = Object.keys(data)
                   .map(key => ({id: Number(key), name: data[key]}));

console.log(result);
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I really need to get better at .map()! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad for adding the resources. #teachamantofish that helped me solve my own problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your object instance is named `obj`:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return [...acc, { id: curr, name: obj[curr] }]
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

the trivial way

```
var o = {
    "1": "Technology",
    "2": "Startup",
    "3": "IT",
};
var arr = [];
for(var i in o) {
    arr.push({
        id: i,
        number: o[i]
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to turn an object into an array of key-value pairs (also stored as an array).

This allows us to take advantage of [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) so we can make this a nice one-liner:

```js
const obj = {
  "1": "Technology",
  "2": "Startup",
  "3": "IT",
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([id, name]) => ({id: +id, name}));

console.log(result);
```

Adding in a [unary plus (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to turn the id (which is a string) into a number.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const words = {
  told: 64,
  mistake: 11,
  thought: 16,
  bad: 17
}

const results = []

Object.entries(words).map(val => results.push({
  text: val[0],
  value: val[1]
}))

console.log(results)
```

Comment: The `map` method is used to project new values from the current ones and ***return the result***. You should be using `.forEach()` instead.

Comment: can you explain in more details why should be use forEach instead of map method