# Make new object array from object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have object like:

```
let obj = {
 type: 1
 name: 'Test'
 pr: 0
 g: 1
}
```

and i wan't to make like this object with it:

```
   obj = [
    {
      title: "type",
      value: 1,
    },
    {
      title: "name",
      value: "Test",
    },
    {
      title: "pr",
      value: 0,
    },
    { title: "gr", value: 1 },
  ];
```

so basically first key will be in name and second key will be value.

What i tried?

```
 newObj = Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        obj = {
          name: key,
          value: key,
        };
      });
```

it's worked but it's give just first 2 value of the object and not makes object array.

so output is :

```
obj = {
  name: type,
  value: 1,
};
```

another entries not visible.

What i need to do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert object to an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345341/convert-object-to-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const obj = {
 type: 1,
 name: 'Test',
 pr: 0,
 g: 1
};


const res = Object.entries(obj)
                  .map(([title, value]) => ({title, value}));

console.log(res);
```

If you're not familiar with this syntax:

```
([title, value]) => ({title, value})
```

It could be rewritten as:

```
function (x) { return { title: x[0], value: x[1] }; }
```

But in the above example, I used a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to create 2 variables `title` and `value` from the provided key/value pair.

And `{title, value}` is just a shorthand syntax for `{ title: title, value: value }`.

Comment: I now realize that some of the syntax I used here may be unclear. Don't hesitate if you need an explanation about what's inside the `.map()`. `([title, value])` is actually a single parameter (the current [key,value] array), but we destructure it into separate variables, using a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). An then `{title, value}` is a shorthand syntax for `{ title: title, value: value}`

Comment: @blex One suggestion though, add this explanation to answer. People mostly tend to have a look into the answer not comments. I found it is very helpful and informative.

Comment: @Karan Thanks for the feedback, I added it

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do this by reduce method with Object.keys(), as an alternative:

```js
let obj = {
  type: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  pr: 0,
  g: 1,
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return [...acc, {
    title: rec,
    value: obj[rec]
  }]
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(...)` and use `map` to get your desired result like below.

`Object.keys(obj).map(x => ({ title: x, value: obj[x] }));`

```js
const obj = {
  type: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  pr: 0,
  g: 1
};


const res = Object.keys(obj).map(x => ({ title: x, value: obj[x] }));
console.log(res);
```