# How to add ids to every element of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I have an object which has some values like "1", "5", "6" etc and refers to "data1", "data2", "data3" etc as an object.

I am trying to map this object but it is not mapping and looking for id. Here is the object that I am talking about:

```
[
  {
    "1": "data1",
    "5": "data2",
    "6": "data3"
  }
]
```

And here is the object that I need:

```
[
  {
    id: "0",
    ids: "1",
    data: "data1"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    ids: "5",
    data: "data2"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    ids: "6",
    data: "data3"
  },
  }
]
```

Is there a way to solve this automatically from the response by JavaScript?

I have this response in my React app and specifically using Refine framework(refine.dev) and when I try to map this response, it is looking for reference. I tried every possible answer here: [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)  but has no luck for my case.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, your initial data is an object or an array of object? Cause you said you want to map an object but your sample code is array of object

Comment: Use the answers to [Convert object to an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49345341/215552), just add an `id` property that is the index.

Comment: are you talking about the hooks in refine returning the data property like`const lastUpdated = tableQueryResult?.data?.data?.lastUpdated;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let obj = {
  "1": "data1",
  "5": "data2",
  "6": "data3"
};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);
let resultArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const tempObj = {
    id: i,
    ids: keys[i],
    data: obj[keys[i]]
  };

  resultArray.push(tempObj);
}


console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the confusing part whas that there is an object inside an array:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "1": "data1",
    "5": "data2",
    "6": "data3"
  }
]

res = Object.entries(arr[0]).map( ([ids,data],index) => ({
  id: index,
  ids,
  data
  })  )
  
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using for...in on the object.  I'm not sure if you'll ever have more than 1 object in your starting array but if you pull the object out, you can iterate over the key values.

```js
const startingData = [
  {
    "1": "data1",
    "5": "data2",
    "6": "data3"
  }
];

const objectToLoop = startingData[0];
const endingData = [];
let i = 0;
for(const entry in objectToLoop){
  
  let itemToAdd = {
    id: i,
    ids: entry,
    data: objectToLoop[entry] 
  };

endingData.push(itemToAdd);
i++;
}

console.log(endingData);
```

Comment: you dont increment i.

Comment: thanks for that catch!

Answer (score 1):

```
const sample = {
  "1": "data1",
  "5": "data2",
  "6": "data3"
};

function init(input) {
  let result = [];

  const keys = Object.keys(input);

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    const label = keys[i];
    const value = input[label];

    result = [
      ...result,
      {
        id: `${i}`,
        ids: `${label}`,
        data: `${value}`,
      }
    ];
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(init(sample));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const test = [
  {
    "1": "data1",
    "5": "data2",
    "6": "data3"
  }
];

let result = [];
Object.entries(test[0]).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
  result.push({
      id: index,
      ids:key,
      data: value
  });
});
console.log(result);
```