# How to swap keys and values in an object? JS

Tags: javascript

Please tell me how to get such an array where id : newExcluded(key), and excluded :(newExcluded value )

```
  const newExcluded = {1:true,6:false,3:false,4:true,7:true}
    
     coonst fetchExcluded = [
        {"id": 1,"excluded": true},
        {"id": 6, "excluded": false},
        {"id": 3, "excluded": false},
        {"id": 4, "excluded": true},
        {"id": 7, "excluded": true},
       ]
```

Comment: Loop `newExcluded` and construct new array `fetchExcluded`

Comment: do not tell me how to do it through map

Comment: What's wrong with `map`? @AramGasparyan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert object to an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345341/convert-object-to-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Object.entries` to convert it to an array of arrays and `Array.prototype.map` to convert each inner array to an object with the required properties

```js
const newExcluded = {1:true,6:false,3:false,4:true,7:true}

fetchExcluded = Object.entries(newExcluded).map(([id, excluded]) => ({ id, excluded }));

console.log(fetchExcluded);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Without* using `map`.

[Iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) (this returns an array which is why we're using `for/of`), and assign the key/value of each property to a new object.

```js
const obj = {1:true,6:false,3:false,4:true,7:true};

const output = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  output[key] = value;
}

console.log(output);
```